# How to enable IntelliSense in WebStorm for implicitly imported modules

Tags: sails.js, webstorm

I'm currently working on a SailsJS project, where the import and export of modules are wired up under cover. So I'm wondering if there is any annotation that I can put in the front of a module to tell WebStorm the dependencies of it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: would you like to enable completion for such modules? the only way to let WebStorm know about them is downloading/creating the corresponding libraries (actual modules, or just stubs, like typescript .d.ts files). see http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/07/how-webstorm-works-completion-for-javascript-libraries/

Comment: Not exactly. The modules depend on each other without explicit "require". I'm just wondering if there is a way to tell WebStorm that this variable is from module A and that is from module B. Very nice tips though. :)